# How to get the list for nsepy package index naming conventions

Tags: python, nsepy

```
data = get_history(symbol="NIFTY BANK", start=from_date, end=to_date,index=True, option_type = 'CE', strike_price = 38000, expiry_date = dt.date(2021, 10, 7))
```

Using the above code but getting returned blank dataframe.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.